# I got error like Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { : argument is of length zero when I use Phantomjs(port = 4567l)

Tags: r, phantomjs, screen-scraping, rselenium, bigdata

my code is

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
pDrv <- phantomjs(port = 4567L)
```

below is what I got an error after runing above codes.

```
    checking phantomjs versions:
    BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
    BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
    Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { : 
      argument is of length zero
```

this problem has baffled me for couple of weeks, since I changed my laptop and upgrade to win10 ,never can it run well as before ,pls help me .

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
binman::rm_platform("phantomjs")
wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE)
```

If error still comes out, then go [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) do download zip file. Unzip it, gett the .exe file, put it into usually this folder (yours may be different)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\binman\binman_phantomjs\windows\2.1.1
```