# RSelenium Setup Error: "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to learn Rselenium to scrape web data, but I can't get past square one. Here's my code:

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("tidyverse")

library(RSelenium)

driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                              chromever =
                                system2(command = "wmic",
                                        args = 'datafile where name="C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
                                        stdout = TRUE,
                                        stderr = TRUE) %>%
                                stringr::str_extract(pattern = "(?<=Version=)\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.") %>%
                                magrittr::extract(!is.na(.)) %>%
                                stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\.",
                                                         replacement = "\\\\.") %>%
                                paste0("^",  .) %>%
                                stringr::str_subset(string =
                                                      binman::list_versions(appname = "chromedriver") %>%
                                                      dplyr::last()) %>%
                                as.numeric_version() %>%
                                max() %>%
                                as.character())
```

And my results:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in if (file.access(selpath, 1) < 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I can't find an answer that gets to this error with RSelenium so early in the process.

I tried the solution recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202062/i-got-error-like-error-in-if-file-accessphantompath-1-0-argument-is-o):

```
binman::rm_platform("phantomjs")
wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE)
```

I tried downloading the phantomjs.exe and placed it in 'dir/binman/binman_phantomjs/'

But no luck, running line 2 there returns the same error. Is there something I'm supposed to define that I haven't?

TIA for any help!