Extract percentiles values from Scopus using R
I'm trying to get the Highest percentile value from Scopus for all the journals.
The URL is: https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri
This values is updated every year, so the value for each year is even better.
There's no way to get this data using its API.
I tried rvestbut no success.
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri"

site <- read_html(url)

site %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   ``         CiteScore CiteScoreTracker 
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>            
#> 1 Calculated Annually  12 times per year
#> 2 Updates    None      Monthly

Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.0.2

What code have you tried already? A good place to start for web scraping would be rvest. It looks like your data is contained in an HTML table that you can extract with CSS selectors based on <table class="table main-table" id="sourceResults">. Best of luck :)

Yeah, I tried rvest but not success. Updated my question

You can do it with rvest and httr.
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

# URL and header
url <- "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri"
headers <- c(
  `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/108.0.0.0"
)

# Payload
payload <- list(
  `sortField` = "citescore",
  `sortDirection` = "desc",
  `sourceSelectionType` = "all",
  `sourceIds` = "28773,20315,15847,16590,20425,15819,21100812243,23340,18434,12464,29719,19300156903,21206,21318,17900156715,21100812579,23350,24004,17700156734,21100220495",
  `resultsListTypeValue` = "Sources",
  `sourcePageDataSource` = "All",
  `year` = "2022",
  `offset` = "0", ### Iterate along this parameter in a for or purrr loop!
  `resultsPerPage` = "20"
)

# POST request
response <- POST(url, body = payload, encode = "form", add_headers(.headers=headers))

# gets the results on a weird data-frame format
page = content(response)
result = page |> 
  html_element("#resultsJson") |> 
  html_text() |> 
  fromJSON()
result = result[["results"]]

The secret is pretending to make the request from a browser (User-Agent). The payload sets the conditions of the search. For the final step, you only need to iterate this process along the "offset" argument.

I didn't try but your solutions looks smart. How do you know which parameters to use in the body? Also, I wonder why a POST request is working while the server is expecting a GET (since it is visited by a browser). Am I loosing anything? Thanks!

I tried to iterate but I get repeated results in the iterations. I post a different answer comparing the results with my solution and yours. Can you check if something is wrongly applied?

I got the parameter while looking the Network tab on the "Inspect element" window of the browser. The first request usually has all the information you need. In it, there were many headers and payload arguments.
About my code, you have to use multiples of 20. i.e.: 0, 20, 40, 60, ...
The offset means how many lines to skip on the data. If you are collecting 20 each time you have to skip 20 each time.

I tried the answer by Icaro Bernardes but I got repeated results. Below I compare both solutions (using httr and RSelenium). I'm probably missing something.
EDITED: I edited according to Bruno Mioto. Now both solutions gives the same result. httr solution is faster and the results are with a better format.
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# URL and header
url <- "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri"

# HTTR solution ---------------------------------------------------------------

headers <- c(
  `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/108.0.0.0"
)

get_httr <- function(i){
  # Payload
  payload <- list(
    `sortField` = "citescore",
    `sortDirection` = "desc",
    `sourceSelectionType` = "all",
    `sourceIds` = "28773,20315,15847,16590,20425,15819,21100812243,23340,18434,12464,29719,19300156903,21206,21318,17900156715,21100812579,23350,24004,17700156734,21100220495",
    `resultsListTypeValue` = "Sources",
    `sourcePageDataSource` = "All",
    `year` = "2022",
    `offset` = as.character(i), ### Iterate along this parameter in a for or purrr loop!
    `resultsPerPage` = "20"
  )
  
  cat(payload$offset, "- ")
  
  # POST request
  response <- POST(url, body = payload, encode = "form", add_headers(.headers=headers))
  
  # gets the results on a weird data-frame format
  page = content(response)
  result = page |> 
    html_element("#resultsJson") |> 
    html_text() |> 
    fromJSON()
  result[["results"]]
}

# Apply 50 iterations and keep unique
iter <- seq(0, 980, 20)
results_httr <- lapply(iter, \(x) get_httr(x)) |> 
  list_rbind() |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  distinct(title, .keep_all = TRUE)

nrow(results_httr)
#> [1] 1000

# RSelenium solution -----------------------------------------------------------

get_selenium <- function(i, remDr){
  cat(i, "- ")
  if (i != 1) {
    webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"sourceResults-nextPage")
    webElem$clickElement()
  } 
  
  html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  site <- read_html(html)
  
  site |>
    html_node("body") |>
    html_node("#sourceResults") |>  
    html_table()
}

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4555L, verbose=F, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)

# Apply 50 iterations and keep unique
results_sel <- lapply(1:50, \(i) get_selenium(i, remDr)) |> 
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |> 
  dplyr::distinct(`Source title`, .keep_all = TRUE)

nrow(results_sel)
#> [1] 1000


The offset argument is about the number of rows you want to skip, so it's offset=0, then offset = 50...
And we can see that the website returns 1000 results maximum. How can we get all 45,805 journals?

Even when logged with my University account, I can only see 1000 results. I have no idea how to visualize the rest, not even in the browser.

Try this:
library(rvest)
library(tibble)

url <- "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri"

page <- read_html_live(url)

tibble(
  source = page %>% html_elements("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text(),
  pct = page %>% html_elements("td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text(),
)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 2
#>    source                                     pct                               
#>    <chr>                                      <chr>                             
#>  1 Ca-A Cancer Journal for Clinicians         99%1/366Oncology                  
#>  2 Nature Reviews Molecular Cell Biology      99%1/380Molecular Biology         
#>  3 New England Journal of Medicine            99%1/830General Medicine          
#>  4 The Lancet                                 99%2/830General Medicine          
#>  5 Nature Reviews Drug Discovery              99%1/301Pharmacology              
#>  6 Nature Medicine                            99%1/212General Biochemistry, Gen…
#>  7 Nature Reviews Materials                   99%1/306Materials Chemistry       
#>  8 Chemical Reviews                           99%1/407General Chemistry         
#>  9 Cell                                       99%2/212General Biochemistry, Gen…
#> 10 Nature Reviews Cancer                      99%1/214Cancer Research           
#> 11 Reviews of Modern Physics                  99%1/240General Physics and Astro…
#> 12 Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning 99%1/404Software                  
#> 13 Nature                                     99%1/134                          
#> 14 Nature Reviews Immunology                  99%1/217Immunology                
#> 15 IEEE Communications Surveys and Tutorials  99%1/738Electrical and Electronic…
#> 16 Nature Energy                              99%1/252Energy Engineering and Po…
#> 17 Chemical Society Reviews                   99%2/407General Chemistry         
#> 18 Physiological Reviews                      99%1/182Physiology                
#> 19 Nature Reviews Clinical Oncology           99%3/366Oncology                  
#> 20 The Lancet Respiratory Medicine            99%1/144Pulmonary and Respiratory…

Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.1.0

That's great, but I would like to get all journals, not only the first 20. Thanks again for your help!

When this open issue is fixed, it should be possible to click through the pages.

You can combine rvest with RSelenium to get all the pages. I tried to combine all of them using list_rbind but there are some problems with type conversion. I believe you will figure it out.
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(purrr)

get_table <- function(i, remDr){
  if (i != 1) {
    webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"sourceResults-nextPage")
    webElem$clickElement()
  } 
  
  html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  site <- read_html(html)
  
  site |>
    html_node("body") |>
    html_node("#sourceResults") |>  
    html_table()
}

url <- "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri"
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4555L, verbose=F, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)


map(1:50, \(i) get_table(i, remDr))



rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4555L, verbose=F, chromever = NULL)
Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { :
argument is of length zero


Is firefox installed in your pc? I also had some problem making this work. I can search for your error.

Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202062/i-got-error-like-error-in-if-file-accessphantompath-1-0-argument-is-o

Some info here as well: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/137
